# Java how to specify the extension on a given file

Tags: java, file

I have this program here that scans for all the files in WinRar folder and determines whether it is a directory or file. However I want to also make it able to determine the extension on the file. For example lets say I have setup.exe in WinRar and the program prints Setup.exe has the extension .exe

```
public class SystemCommands{

public static void main (String args[]){



String dir_name = "C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\"; 
File dir = new File(dir_name);



File[] dir_list = dir.listFiles();
for(int i=0;i<dir_list.length;++i)
{
    System.out.println(dir_list[i].getName());
    System.out.println("Is it a directory = " + dir_list[i].isDirectory());
    System.out.println("Is it a file = " + dir_list[i].isFile());

}

}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use Commons IO, it has [FilenameUtils#getExtension](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(dir_list[i].getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use a one simple line as answered by Thilo but use a 3rd party API for that.
OR
You can find the "." in the absolute file path and then read the Sequence of chars after the "."
example:

```
String path = dir_list[i].getAbsolutePath();
int position  = path.indexOf(".");
String extension = path.subString(position);
```

you should go with Thilo's Answer though :D

Comment: You probably want `lastIndexOf`. And handle the case where there is no dot.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer with a seperate "lastIndexOF" example below mine.. for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Simply parse the path to check the last index of dot (.) and do substring to get extension.

```
private static String getExtension(File file)
    {
        return getExtension(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private static String getExtension(String path)
    {
        String extension = null;

        int lastIndexOfDot = path.lastIndexOf(".");

        if (lastIndexOfDot != -1)
        {
            extension = path.substring(lastIndexOfDot + 1);
        }
        return extension;
    }
```